# Memoize a void recursive function

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I've a recursive function. I need to memoize it but can't find a way to.
Please let me know the way.

Here's the code:

```
int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

void solve(int[] arr, int idx, int sum) {
        if(idx == arr.length) {
            if(sum >= 0)
            ans = Math.min(ans, sum);
            //t[idx] = Math.min(t[idx], su);
            //System.out.println("ans = " + ans);
            return;
        }
        
        //if(t[idx] != 0) return t[idx];
        
        int sum1 = sum, sum2 = sum;
        
        sum1 += arr[idx];
        sum2 += -arr[idx];
        
        solve(arr, idx + 1, sum1);
        
        solve(arr, idx + 1, sum2);
        
        //return t[idx];
    }
```

Thanks in advance from a noob in DP.

Answer (score 0):

All (recursing) calls *seem* to differ, yes? Then memoizing would not help.

But no, for the same `idx` both `sum1` and `sum2` might be equal, when `arr[idx] == 0`.

```
    solve(arr, idx + 1, sum1);
    if (sum2 != sum1) {
        solve(arr, idx + 1, sum2);
    }
```

Neater would be:

```
    int value = arr[idx];
    ++idx;
    solve(arr, idx, sum + value);
    if (value != 0) {
        solve(arr, idx, sum - value;
    }
```

As every recursive call normally would double the further calls, this can reduce *2<sup>n</sup>* drastically to *n* (when all zeroes).

Memoizing means here, if sum2 == sum1 then `ans` is the memoized value.

This indeed is not what one normally understands under memoizing exactly.

In **pseudo-code** that could be:

```
Map<int[], Integer> memoization = new HashMap<>();
void solve(int[] arr, int idx, int sum) {
    if (idx == 0) {
        Integer a = memoization.get(arr);
        if (a != null) {
            ans = a;
            return;
        }
    }
    if (idx == arr.length) {
        memoization.put(arr, Arrays.copy(ans));
    }
    ...
}
```

This does not play out memoization to its fullest, ever sub-array arr[0 .. i] might be memoized. Which just might be the required solution.

The reason that not the usual function - returning some memoized value - is used, but rather an ugly global variable, is that is cummulated. In pure functional style it would need to be both parameter `ansTillNow` and result.

This leaves the hard work to you. Also be aware that the solution actually is astonishing simple, mathematically.

Comment: I think my answer is too mean, so one tip: memoized might not be the input array but just the sum upto idx, mapped to the ans. Then the if is not needed, as the memoization deals with it. (The answers here should explain, not do someones homework.)